# why getActiveSubscriptionInfoList is getting empty for some android 11 devices?

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-subscriptionmanager

I need to find out device SIM card is present or not(including duel sim devices). So that I have tried Subscription Manager **getActiveSubscriptionInfoList** API, but it is returning empty for certain android 11 devices.

Information:

- Slot 1 has a SIM card
- Slot 2 don't have SIM card
- Device OS version: Android 11
- Device Model Name: RMX3085realme
- Network Provider  Jio Prepaid

Comment: hey did you get resolved

Comment: i tried with TelephonyManager#getSimState()

Comment: It may help other users if you marked the answer below which mentions that as the answer in that case.

Comment: How do we use `getSimState()`? Currently I'm getting the list of SIMs by using `subscriptionManager?.activeSubscriptionInfoList`, how do I port it to TelephonyManager?

Answer (score 4):

`SubscriptionManager#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()` returns the subscription list that is provisioned by a carrier application. If no carrier app has successfully notified Android to an available subscription, then this will return empty irregardless of whether there is a sim card or not.

`TelephonyManager#getSimState()`([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getSimState())) is what you want to use if you only want to check if a sim card is present or not as you have stated. As long as `TelephonyManager#getSimState()` does not return `SIM_STATE_ABSENT`([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#SIM_STATE_ABSENT)), that would signify a sim card is present.

Comment: Since you know the problem, How can we solve Carrier app notification issue?

Is there any solution for this. I'm seeing this issue on MIUI devices mostly.

Comment: No, there is no way to use carrier controlled APIs unless you have carrier app privileges AFAIK.

Comment: Let me know if that was what you were referring to, e.g., how to submit subscription info on behalf of the carrier app. If so, then yeah, not possible AFAIK.

Comment: I understand this. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: There's no way to "fix" this issue from my understanding since this is the intended behavior.

Comment: in some devices not able to get SubscriptionManager.from(mContext).getActiveSubscriptionInfoCount() > 1.is that manufacturing defect or what.. ?

Comment: It could be that no subscription exists which could be for a multitude of reasons such as a manufacturing issue but you'll have to debug on a case-by-case basis to confirm.